# What data type should be used for a time column

Tags: apache-spark

In my Spark appliction, I had to split the time and data and store them in separate column  as follow:

```
val df5=df4.withColumn("read_date",date_format(df4.col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).withColumn("read_time",date_format(df4.col("date"), "HH:mm:ss")).drop("date")
```

This command will split data and time

```
------------+-------------
2012-01-12     00:06:00
------------+-------------
```

but creates both fields as String. So, I have to `.cast("date")` for date, but what data type to use for time column? 
If I use like `.cast("timestamp")` it will combine the current server date to the time. As we are going to visualize the data in Power BI, do you think storing the time as String is right approach to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no DataType in Spark to hold 'HH:mm:ss' values. Instead you can use hour(), minute() and second() functions to represent the values respectively.

All these functions return **int** types.

```
hour(string date) -- Returns the hour of the timestamp: hour('2009-07-30 12:58:59') = 12, hour('12:58:59') = 12.

minute(string date) -- Returns the minute of the timestamp.

second(string date) -- Returns the second of the timestamp.
```