# Is there any way to handle time in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a string with 6 characters which should be loaded into SQL Server as the TIME data type.
But spark doesn't have any time data type. I have tried a few ways but data type is not returning in the timestamp.

I am reading the data as a string and converting it to timestamp and then finally trying to extract time values but it is returning value as string again.

```
df.select('time_col').withColumn("time_col",to_timestamp(col("time_col"),"HHmmss").cast(TimestampType())).withColumn("tim2", date_format(col("time_col"), "HHmmss")).printSchema()

root
|-- time_col: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- tim2: string (nullable = true)
```

And the data looks like this but in a different data type.

```
df.select('time_col').withColumn("time_col",to_timestamp(col("time_col"),"HHmmss").cast(TimestampType())).withColumn("tim2", date_format(col("time_col"), "HHmmss")).show(5)

+-------------------+------+
|           time_col|  tim2|
+-------------------+------+
|1970-01-01 14:44:51|144451|
|1970-01-01 14:48:37|144837|
|1970-01-01 14:46:10|144610|
|1970-01-01 11:46:39|114639|
|1970-01-01 17:44:33|174433|
+-------------------+------+
```

Is there any way I can get tim2 column in timestamp column or column equivalent to TIME data type of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't get what you are trying to do, there's no type in PySpark to handle "HH:mm:ss", see: [What data type should be used for a time column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549871/what-data-type-should-be-used-for-a-time-column)

I'd suggest you to use it as string.

Comment: I could use string but the target is TIME in SQL Server and what would it expect from spark? or what will be equivalent of TIME in spark?

Comment: Or you could create a column on SQL Server with type varchar and then convert the string (varchar) to time with something like `SELECT CONVERT( TIME, '10:00:22' );`

Comment: well I would give it a try. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used to convert into timestamp in spark and before sending to SQL server just make it string.. it worked fine with me.

Comment: Convert into timestamp means you are converting a raw string to Timestamp and converting to string before pushing data to SQL?

Comment: In my case I only have time but when I am casting to timestamp date is being appended to my time value which is not what I wanted. Is there any other approach can we try?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you, but it seems to me that this changes the column in str

```
df.withColumn('TIME', date_format('datetime', 'HH:mm:ss'))
```

Answer (score -1):

In scala, python will be similar:

```
scala> val df = Seq("144451","144837").toDF("c").select('c.cast("INT").cast("TIMESTAMP"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [c: timestamp]

scala> df.show()
+-------------------+
|                  c|
+-------------------+
|1970-01-02 17:07:31|
|1970-01-02 17:13:57|
+-------------------+


scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- c: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Yes, it is timestamp but I don't want the preceding date in front. As per my knowledge it is not possible with Timestamp type

Comment: Looks like spark doesn't handle TIME type but DATETIME as spark's TIMESTAMP. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/MsSqlServerDialect.scala